# How to judge the difference in any consecutive rows is greater than 0.1 in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

The data in my csv like this:

```
staff_id,clock_time,device_id,latitude,longitude
1001,2020/9/14 4:43:00,d_1,24.59652556,118.0824644
1001,2020/9/14 8:34:40,d_1,24.59732974,118.0859631
1001,2020/9/14 3:33:34,d_1,24.73208312,118.0957197
1001,2020/9/14 4:17:29,d_1,24.59222786,118.0955275
1001,2020/9/20 5:30:56,d_1,24.59689407,118.2863806
1001,2020/9/20 7:26:05,d_1,24.58237852,118.2858955
```

I want to find any row where the difference between longitude or latitude of 2 consecutive rows is greater than 0.1,then put the row index of two consecutive rows into a list.

From my data, the latitude difference of rows 2(24.59732974), 3(24.73208312), 4(24.59222786) greater than 0.1, and the longitude difference  of rows 4(118.0955275),5(118.2863806) greater than 0.1.

I want to put the indexes of rows 2, 3, 4 into a list `latitude_diff_list`, and put the index of 4,5 rows into another list `longitude_diff_list`, what should I do?

Comment: How is count difference?

Comment: by `diff()` ? Or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need absolute difference between original and shifted values, compared by [`DataFrame.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html) for greater:

```
m1 = df[['latitude','longitude']].diff().abs().gt(0.1)
m2 = df[['latitude','longitude']].shift().diff().abs().gt(0.1)

m = m1 | m2
print (m)
   latitude  longitude
0     False      False
1     False      False
2      True      False
3      True      False
4      True       True
5     False       True

latitude_diff_list = df.index[m['latitude']].tolist()
print (latitude_diff_list)
[2, 3, 4]

longitude_diff_list = df.index[m['longitude']].tolist()
print (longitude_diff_list)
[4, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a combination of `diff()`, to check if the absolute difference with the next or the previous row is more than 0.1, and then get the indices of these rows (I understand you actually want the index, not the descriptive row number, i.e. an index that starts from 0). One way you could do this is:

```
latitude_diff_list = df.index[(abs(df['latitude'].diff()) > 0.1) | (abs(df['latitude'].diff(-1)) > 0.1)].tolist()
longitude_diff_list = df.index[(abs(df['longitude'].diff()) > 0.1) | (abs(df['longitude'].diff(-1)) > 0.1)].tolist()
```

You can then offset this by +1 if you want the row number starting from 1 (e.g. `[i+1 for i in latitude_diff_list]`)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import pandas as pd

df_ex = pandas.read_csv('ex.csv', sep=',')
latitude_diff_list, longitude_diff_list = [], []
for idx,row in df_ex[1:].iterrows():
    if abs(row['latitude'] - df_ex.loc[idx-1, 'latitude']) > 0.1:
        latitude_diff_list.extend([idx-1, idx])
    if abs(row['longitude'] - df_ex.loc[idx-1, 'longitude']) > 0.1:
        longitude_diff_list.extend([idx-1, idx])

latitude_diff_list, longitude_diff_list = list(set(latitude_diff_list)), list(set(longitude_diff_list))
```